# Para o que serve tipo byte Java

Tags: java

Para o que serve o tipo byte do java?
ex:

```
byte[] dados = ... ;
```

Qual a real utilidade?
Alguém tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `byte` é um tipo de dado base (primitivo), que é base da programação, é o tipo de dado de mais baixo nível do Java, com ele o possível criar qualquer outro tipo.

1(um) `byte` é composto de 8(oito) `bits`;

Em linguagens de alto nível como o Java, ele não é tão utilizado em alguns casos. Onde existem outros tipo derivados que se adequam melhor ao caso, como `String`.

Mas se você programar algo que envolva arquivos por exemplo, você já vai se deparar com uma boa utilidade para o mesmo.

Vou tentar lhe apresentar alguns exemplos curriqueiros:

1. Ler arquivo de disco, ou baixar via rede (HTTP ou FTP);
2. Escrever arquivo em disco;
3. Trafegar dados crus pela rede;
4. Manipulação de imagens;
5. Trafego de `Streams`;

Esses são alguns exemplos que já utilizei o tipo `byte`, há muito mais coisa onde se utiliza o tipo `byte`.

A [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) do Java diz o seguinte sobre `byte`:

> The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Várias utilidades, são de no máximo 255 bits podendo também como você postou pode ser um array de bytes. É muito utilizado quando se deseja salvar um arquivo inteiro dentro de um banco de dados. (Array de bytes). Dependendo da proporção que o atributo da sua classe irá demandar, usar byte deixa sua aplicação relativamente mais leve, pois é um tipo de dado primitivo.

Comment: "são de no máximo 255 bits" acho que você quis dizer que ele pode representar valores de `0` a `255`, não? (um byte tem `8` bits, não mais, não menos) De qualquer forma, em Java não existe o tipo *unsigned byte* (byte sem sinal), de modo que os valores representáveis vão de `-128` a `127`. Quando se quer representar valores de `0` a `255`, normalmente se usa um `int` mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, **byte** é um tipo de dados constituído por 8 bites.
Existem diversas utilizações deste tipo de dados, entre elas, por exemplo:

- Máscaras;
- Imagens, Strings, Dll's, entre muitos outros tipos de dados/objectos compilados;
- Streams;
- etc.

Por exemplo, no caso dos streams, cada byte recebido pode ser um caractér e no fim da recepção terá a sua mensagem.

Comment: Um byte não é um caractere, exceto nos casos mais simples (ASCII). É um erro igualar esses dois (da mesma forma que dizer que um caractere Unicode são dois bytes também está incorreto). Sugiro a leitura [desse artigo](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)) (a tradução está meio tosca, mas dá pra pegar a ideia geral).